# When pigtailing a second load to circuit

Tags: electrical-panel

If I add an outlet near the electric panel and pig-tail the hot wire to an existing 15a breaker do I have to attach the neutral and ground to a specific spot or any open slot on their respective bars?

Comment: Where are you located? Depending on your local code, this may trigger the requirement for an AFCI breaker.

Answer (score 1):

Any spot on the neutral bar for the neutral, and ground bar for the ground, will do.

Answer (score 1):

As long as that is the main panel, and not a sub-panel, then both go on the same bar. If it's a sub-panel or four-wire, the neutral goes to the neutral bar. And ground goes to ground bar. Look at wires feeding panel; Three means it's a main panel. Four means it's a sub-panel.

Answer (score -1):

The connections on the neutral and ground bars should be in the same order as the corresponding circuit breakers.

This is neater and makes fault-finding easier. It might not be required by regulations, though.

Comment: Someone downvoted this, maybe because it's a bit whacky and nobody does it.  But if you install and maintain your own panel and nobody else works on it there's no harm in having some system of arranging the neutrals on the bus.  My panel has the bus in two layers, one in front of the other.   I like to keep as much as possible on the rear bus because if the front ones fill up it's harder to work on the rear ones.  Electricians, on the other hand (when I hire them) prefer to add things to the front bus because it's easier and they get the job done faster, which is a valid goal.